# Camshaft sensor testing

Tags: electrical, starting, sensor

this is a 2004 accent diesel , using the scan tool I get bad camshaft sensor malfunctioning and using the multimeter I got those readings on its terminal ( same connected or not )  0V  , 5V  , 12V.

the car doesn't start , tried to force the 5v signal to ground to see if the injection working with it but it didn't 
but in case I start the car by towing or by injecting some gas to the intake while cranking it starts and keeps running
I replaced the sensor but got the same results

what could be the fault here ? ( is the wiring correct ?)

Comment: What's the code? Do you have a scope? If it's a three wire sensor with it unplugged you should see ground, b+ (or 5v) and signal return. without knowing the wiring setup for your car it's hard to say which one the 5v or 12v is your reference voltage. I'd take a good look at a wiring diagram if you're seeing 5v or 12v on the signal return wire there's a short to power somewhere. Tapping the signal wire to ground shouldn't work unless something about diesels is different.

Comment: The code is 340 . no I don't have a scope. It is 3 wire with it unplugged I see ground, 12v and 5v I don't have wiring diagram . I'll see if I can find out the shorting . thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test the sensor, it should just be a [hall effect sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect_sensor). If you pull it out of its home, connect a multimeter set to VDC to the two leads (assuming two leads), then wave any metal object in front of the sensor, you should see movement out of display on the multimeter if the sensor is good. If you don't see activity, it's a pretty good sign it's shot.

Comment: I did this test with no luck ( it has 3 leads - S + ) but what bothers me is the injectors are not responding to the bypass test of the sensor !

Comment: If you are not getting signal from the sensor, I'd think you'd want to start there in your diagnostics by changing it. If you are pretty sure it's bad (due to no signal), it would be the place I'd start.

Comment: Thank you for the help . as i said i have. Replaced the sensor. But still get the same error code . and to eliminate the sensor from the equation i removed the harness and kept pulling the signal wire to ground this is supposed to fool the ecu into activating the injectors but that didn't work which is making me believe the fault is on the ecu side

Comment: Is the power to the sensor supposed to be ave while signal only 5v ?